# How to ask a question about reasons behind electrical code?

Tags: discussion, questions

Out of curiosity, and to learn something, I want to learn about reasons behind electrical codes (for this purpose, it doesn't matter which ones). Especially since it's often mentioned on the site that there *are* reasons behind code, ones which we may fail to notice ourselves.

At first I wanted to ask about resources to learn this from, but that would encourage link-only answers and generally bad form. An alternative that comes to mind is to ask a list question, with one rule and reason per answer, if that is allowed.

Or is this simply not a question for this site? Although I do believe such a resource would be valuable.

Answer (score 2):

The most accurate way would be to review the Code Making Panel documents on the website of the [NFPA](https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=70) (owners of the NEC).

The site is a bit clunky, and requires a free membership, but many documents back to 1968 are available on their website.